# Ignore larger font size

Tags: vb.net, fonts

I'm not sure if this is a Windows feature or it is a part of the video driver, but when you change screen resolutions you have the option of making the font size 125% or 150% of normal. This causes me endless headaches when designing forms because one woman in the office has her's set to 125%. Before I publish I must set my development machine to match her resolution to make sure everything is visible. This means logging off and on.

Is there a way to have VB.Net ignore that so it does not increase the font size and stretch controls to accommodate? I've noticed that it does not appear all programs increase font size.

Greg

Comment: that woman increased the font size for a reason. "endless headaches" are why professional developers get the big bucks

Comment: I assume you are using Winforms? If so check out this blog on the subject from Telerick: [WinForms scaling at large DPI settings – is it even possible?](http://blogs.telerik.com/winformsteam/posts/14-02-11/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-)

Comment: Plutonix, you must have a lot of time on your hands to have the time to make a comment like that. Obviously not a professional programmer.